# the function "reader.onload" is showing error in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to upload an image on my html page using the below code.

```
 <img id="blah" class="target" alt="your image" 
  src="http://placehold.it/180"  />
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="readURL(this)" />


   function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = (function (e) {
         console.log(e.target.result);
           $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);        
       })();

     }
   }
```

I expect the output to b an image in the img tag.

Comment: "is showing error in js" — Tell us what the error message says!

Comment: By wrapping the function in brackets and then adding brackets afterwards you're basically executing the function immediately and setting `reader.onload` to the result of that function at that time.  Remove the brackets so it's just `reader.onload = function(e) { etc... };`  The will create a function, but not execute it, until it is called by the onload event.

Comment: still not working.Now there is no error but the image tag doesn't show the required image

Comment: As @Archer said, remove the part that makes it execute the function immediately so it becomes `reader.onload = function (e) { ... }` intead of `reader.onload = function (e) { ... }()`

Also I'm not sure if you just left it out of the question but you didn't specify a file to read as shown here [File Reader onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload).

Comment: "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" this error has popped

Answer (score 0):

```
function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       reader.onload = (function (e) {
          document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute('src',reader.result);   
     });
   }
   }
```

Comment: GET file:///Users/shaurya/Desktop/FinalYearProject/publicstatic/Homeuploadproduct/null net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: This error means that file was not found. Either path is wrong or file is not present where you want it to be.